# Parallelizing for-loop inside another loop efficiently with OpenMP

Tags: c++, openmp

I have a problem writing the parallel instructions for a code that work like this:

```
// every iteration depends on the previous one
for (int iter = 0; iter < numIters; ++i)
{
    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(numThreads)
    for (int p = 0; p < numParticles; ++p)
    {
        p_velocity_calculation(...);
    }

    // implicit sync barrier

    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(numThreads)
    for (int p = 0; p < numParticles; ++p)
    {
        p_position_calculation(...);
    }
}
```

The program is about a n-body simulation where first I need to calculate the velocities and then the positions of a set of particles, hence the separation of the two for-loops.

The code runs as expected, but from what I have inquired, the thread pools created by the #pragma omp directives are created and destroyed every iteration of the outer for-loop, but I don't want to waste resources creating them.

So my question is how can I reuse those thread pools and not creating/destroying the threads every iteration?

Comment: To my knowledge, no, general problem of using multiple threads. You might want to look at processes to do that. Look up the `fork` command on how to create them. This will bring you the problem on how to communicate between these processes, probably pipes I guess? Definitively more complex them omp, but I am not aware of a solution within omp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: the thread pools are not destroyed, only suspended.

Next: Have you timed this and found that creating the threads is a limiting factor in your application? If not, don't worry.

Or to put it constructively : I have timed it and unless you have an extremely short `omp parallel for` and you call it tens of thousand of times, the overhead is negligible.

But if you are really worried, put the `omp parallel` outside the time loop, and do an `omp for` around the particle loop. You will do some redundant work between the for loops, which you can either accept or put a `omp master` around if it affects global variables.

But really: I wouldn't worry.